# How to prevent or make Data Interpreter to take only the first row in your CSV file to take as headers..?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I connected a new data source, a CSV file, in tableau, and the headers are displayed as F1, F2, and F3, so I did some googling. I found that I can use Data Interpreter to fix the issue, but after clicking it, it takes both the first and second rows combined as headers. Still, I only want the first row to be headers.. how do I make sure that only the first row is treated as headers instead of the first and second row combined.

I am attaching the screenshots for reference.

before using the data interpreter

[image: before using the data interpreter]

after using the data interpreter

[image: after using the data interpreter]